# to get current generic item item inside of CollectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, collections

I have a custom collection that inherits IEnumerable.

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>   
{
    private ObservableCollection<T> currentList = new ObservableCollection<T>();

    public ObservableCollection<T> Items
    {
        get { return currentList; }  
        set { currentList = value; }
    }

    private List<T> deletedList = new List<T>();
    private List<T> addedList = new List<T>();

    public MyCollection(IEnumerable<T> currentList)
    {
        this.currentList = new ObservableCollection<T>(currentList);
        Items.CollectionChanged+=Items_CollectionChanged;
    }
}
```

I wish to track which items were added or deleted . Also , My Items is databound to a UI datagrid in WPF. The binding works fine if i bind to the Items instead of MyCollection . However , I want to track the added , removed items as below.
Am assuming the following event is caught when I add or remove any item from the UI.

As each row gets added to the DataGrid , I wish this even to be called to save the last added entry.

Now how do I get the current added or removed item in this ?

```
private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{  
    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
    {
        //this doesn't work  ( I List is not assignable to IEnumerable T
        deletedList.AddRange(e.OldItems);
    }

    if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
    {
        //this doesnt work 
        addedList.AddRange(e.OldItems);
    }
}
```

I only get the added or deleted items .

```
public ObservableCollection<T> GetAddedChanges()
{
    var added = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    addedList.ToList().ForEach(added.Add);

    return added;
}

public ObservableCollection<T> GetDeletedChanges()
{
    var deleted = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    deletedList.ToList().ForEach(deleted.Add);
    return deleted;
}
```

UPDATE :
The initial answer here worked i.e the Cast() option and I was able to get only the added members from my list and save them.

There is another issue . I am getting my server to return MyCollection . The sad thing is that my server when it de serializes to collection objects , it gets caught by the Added event of the Items_CollectionChanged  , hence my added List faultily returns 2 items in added list always .

To solve this :

1) Subscribe to the event after server returns instead of MyCollection constructor. i.e Subscribe in another StartTracking( ).

2) Clear the added, deletd lists after getting the response from server .

Which of these would be better ? And are there any alternate solutions ?

This is the flow basically :

UI -- > OBservableCollection --> MyCollection ( where I track added /del elements )  --> Save to Server    ..   To fetch from server , I have my server side code return MyCollectionwith entries in it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your MyCollection class. You have a method called DataTransferObjectCollection with no return type, so effectively it is a constructor with the wrong name

Comment: sorry.. renamed it. that was the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OldItems` is not generic (it is `IList` not `IList<T>`), so you will need to cast the items.

Either:

```
foreach(T item in e.OldItems)
{
    deletedList.Add(item);
}
```

Or:

```
deletedList.AddRange(e.OldItems.Cast<T>());
```

On tracking additions, you'll want to use `NewItems`.  As an aside, this will not capture changes occurring during replace (e.g. `c[0] = <new item>`) or reset (e.g. after `Clear` is called).

I'd also note your `GetAddedChanges` could be simplified (And similarly `GetDeletedChanges`):

```
return new ObservableCollection<T>(addedList);
```

Though it's not clear why the return type would need to be `ObservableCollection<T>`.

Comment: I'd get your server to just return `IEnumerable<T>` - you can create your custom collection from this using its constructor after the items are retrieved.  I don't see any particular reason the server needs to depend on the custom collection (in fact, it's making life complicated!).